# Probability exercise, dependent events.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

7 persons take a tram, boarding at random in 3 wagons. What is the probability that 4 persons will get in the first wagon?

I tried to solve it like this:

P(1 person will get in the first wagon) = 1/3

P(2 persons) = 1/3 * P(1 person), since the events depend on each other.
So P(4 persons) = ( 1/3 )^ 4 = 1/81

Is this correct?

Comment: You're far more likely to get an answer to your question if you include (by editing your post) any attempt you've made to solve the problem on your own and explain where you're stuck. In it's current state your question is likely to attract downvotes as it doesn't include this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

The answer is

$$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}}.$$

Here,

$D = 3^7$ and $N = $ the number of different ways that the 7 people can board so that (presumably) **exactly** $4$ of the $7$ go in the first wagon.

Questions:

How many ways are there of selecting the 4 people out of 7 who will go into the first wagon?

For a given selection of 4 people out of 7 to go into the first wagon, how many ways are there of distributing the remaining 3 people among the remaining 2 wagons?

Comment: So i think the answer to the first question is Combinations of 4 out of 7.

Comment: @vladMXc yes $\binom{7}{4}.$

Comment: And for the second i assume there can be a 1 with 2, 2 with 1 , 0 with 3, 3 with 0 :-?

Comment: @vladMXc No, you're confused.  Think about how I calculated the denominator of $3^7$.  There will be three people remaining, and each person will have 2 choices.  Therefore, the answer to the 2nd question is $2^3.$

Comment: Oh okay :( So the answer is 3^7 / [ C(7 4) - 2 ^3 ] ?

Comment: @vladMXc The answer is $$\frac{\binom{7}{4} \times 2^3}{3^7}.$$

Comment: But.. if it was to distribute 3 people among 2 wagons, shouldn't they either go 1 in the first , 2 in the second or 2 in the first 1 in the second, or 3 in the first  0 in the second or 3 in the second 0 in the first? What are the remaining 4 cases, up to 2^3 in total?

Comment: @vladMXc There are 3 different ways that the 3 people can go 1 in the first, 2 in the second; that is there are 3 different ways of determining which of the 3 people will be alone.  Similarly, there are 3 different ways that the 3 people can go 2 in the first, 1 in the second.  Then, there is only 1 way that all three people can go in the first and only 1 way that all three people can go in the second.  Compare the coeffiicents $\{1,3,3,1\}$ to the 3rd row of Pascal's triangle.  It is not a coincidence that these coefficients appear in the binomial expansion of $8 = 2^3 = (1 + 1)^3.$

Comment: Oh, i get it now! Thank you very much for your time and answers! :)